# Carboy dimensions

Tags: carboy, equipment

What are the dimensions of a 5.5 and 6 gallon standard glass carboy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine are:

- 6.5 Gallon: 20.5" tall (neck included) X 12" in diameter
- 5 Gallon: 19.25" tall (neck included) X 10.5" in diameter

Comment: You beat me to it.  I have the same measurments.

Comment: I had the empties and a measuring tape out when I was messing with that auto siphon question.  Made sense to field this one.